# List View Builder size based on content

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a tab bar, every tab has a different amount of list

here is the code

```
        Column(
          children: [
            TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              indicator: new BubbleTabIndicator(
                indicatorHeight: 25.0,
                indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                tabBarIndicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              ),
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'one'),
                Tab(text: 'two'),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  itemCount: 10,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      Center(child: Text('${index + 1}')),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  itemCount: 20,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      Center(child: Text('${index + 1}')),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

screenshot:

[image]

[image]

in second image I can't scroll down because I give it a height

by the way I used CustomScrollView and it has a SliverPersistentHeader

what I need is to remove Container height and let the size of body be based on content

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't scroll because you're using `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`. if you remove that it should scroll. then you can also remove the container.

For the body to expand to content size with a `CustomScrollView`, use should switch your `ListView`s to `SliverList`s but that means you need to remove your `Column` and `TabBarView` widgets. so just try my first suggestion of removing `physics` from your listViews and hope that works!

If you added `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` because of the scroll glow then I have a package that removes the glowing effect, called [no_scroll_glow](https://pub.dev/packages/no_scroll_glow).